# Runtime error happens when deleting a node of the linklist

Tags: c++

Here's my C++ code of a simple structured linklist.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node(){
        data=-1;
        next=NULL;
        prev=NULL;
    }
    Node(int d,Node *nnext){
        data=d;
        next=nnext;
    }
    void add(Node* nnext){
        next=nnext;
        nnext->prev=this;
    }

};
void print(Node*  head){
    Node* cNode;
    cNode=head;
    while (cNode!=NULL){
        cout <<"["<<cNode->data<<"]" << endl;
        cNode=cNode->next;
    }
}
void insertAfter(Node* pNode, Node* nNode){
    nNode->next = pNode->next;
    pNode->next = nNode;
    pNode->next->prev = nNode;

}
void deleteNode(Node* b){

    Node* c=b->next;
    Node* a=b->prev;
    a->next=c;
    c->prev=a;
    delete b;

}
void main(){
    Node* head;
    head=new Node();
    head->data=1;
    Node * currentNode=head;
    for (int i=2;i<=5;i++){
        Node* nNode=new Node(i,NULL);
        currentNode->add(nNode);
        currentNode=nNode;
    }
    cout << currentNode->data << endl;
    print(head);
    insertAfter(head, new Node(99,NULL));
    //deleteNode(currentNode);
    print(head);

}
```

The case checking is unnecessary because I just need the concept of the linklist. If you have another version of these kind of simple linklist code, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] as well as a **clear problem statement**. Also `void main()` is wrong.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your `deleteNode()` function does not check whether `c` and `a` are non-NULL, but immediately dereferences them. This means that your program will crash if you try to delete the first or last node of the list.

Your `insertAfter()` function also sets pointers in the wrong order, causing `nNode->prev` to point to itself.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you very much that works!

Answer (score 1):

Your deleteNode function is not taking care of the case when you delete the "head" element.

Let's take this list as an example:

head -> n1 -> n2 -> n3  (each of this nodes also has a link to the node before it, just as you did in your code)

If you call deleteNode(head), the following will happen:

```
Node* c=b->next;  // b = head, c = head.next = n1
Node* a=b->prev;  // b = head, a = head.prev = NULL
a->next=c;        // a = NULL, then NULL->next
```

You can't access to a variable of a NULL object, that's why you are receiving that runtime error.

P.S: If you want to improve you understanding of data structures I recomend you this book: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms

Comment: It's a great book. The only flaw is that sometimes they switch halfway explaining a datastructure between showing code using NULL pointers and code using guard pointers, adding some unnecessary confusion.